# Can a data subject be asked to share a limited part of their data if it would be in their interest to do so?

Tags: gdpr

I am an adviser for a UK agency that provides free advice to the public. I have two employment cases that differ in detail, but are fundamentally the same issues and involve the same company. It could benefit both clients if they were aware of the other case, by showing a pattern of behaviour by the employer. Can they agree to us sharing their name and telephone number with the other client?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking. It seems like you might be asking for an interpretation of the GDPR in the UK, but it is not clear to me. You might try to use the "edit" button and think about how this question is viewed by someone who is new to the situation.

Answer (score 1):

If at least one client agrees to such processing of personal data, then yes, you can share his or her phone and name. Consider, however, whether the transfer of personal data is necessary because Article 5(1) of the GDPR states that:

> Personal data shall be (...) collected for specified, explicit and legitimate purposes and not further processed in a manner that is incompatible with those purposes; (...) **adequate, relevant and limited to what is necessary in relation to the purposes for which they are processed**;

How potentially unlimited sharing of someone's phone number and the name is to help with "showing a pattern of behavior by the employer"? Think about how you explain everything to the client in accordance with Article 13 of GDPR.

Comment: If you ask for consent, is must be specific. Potentially unlimited sharing is not specific. So you can only ask to share data with the currently known other client. So it will be adequate, relevant and limited. See also [Art. 13(3)](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-13-gdpr/): _Where the controller intends to further process the personal data for a purpose other than that for which the personal data were collected, the controller shall provide the data subject prior to that further processing with information on that other purpose and with any relevant further information as referred to in paragraph 2_